# Every MSSQL transaction log backup increases in size, but the log is being truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

A client's database is used at a steady pace, the number of transactions should be roughly the same from hour to hour. I ran DBCC SQLPERF (LOGSPACE) immediately after a log backup and the space used had reduced from around 30% just prior to the backup, to 3%, so the log backups are flushing most data from the transaction log. So why is it that every single transaction log backup is slightly larger than the last? I would expect transaction log backup size would stay roughly the same, fluctuating in both directions, but these get bigger EVERY time. Please see screenshot of the [Ever increasing log backups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIwhj.png)

I also ran DBCC OPENTRAN a few times when the backups were being taken, no active open transactions.

Comment: Hmm... that is interesting, though the klaxons aren't going off for me just yet. You can look at LSN information according to the backup in msdb.dbo.backupset. Is the value for first_lsn changing (that is, increasing) from backup to backup? If not, *something* is holding on to the log. Also, a quick check in sys.databases (specifically at log_reuse_wait_desc) will tell you if there's something exotic (i.e. replication, mirroring, availability groups) holding onto the log.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. The first_lsn is increasing with each backup and log_reuse_wait_desc = LOG_BACKUP, so all OK there I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I ran DBCC SQLPERF (LOGSPACE) immediately after a log backup and the space used had reduced from around 30% just prior to the backup, to 3%, so the log backups are flushing most data from the transaction log.

That's a good thing :) There doesn't seem to be anything wrong, then.

> So why is it that every single transaction log backup is slightly larger than the last?

According to the picture that isn't quite the case (the one at midnight is 1.5x larger than the others) but let's not get hung up on technicalities (though it's a technical question [bad pun]).

> A client's database is used at a steady pace, the number of transactions should be roughly the same from hour to hour

Let's *assume* this is the case, the same *number* of transactions occur. Does this mean the transactions are all the same *size*? No, it does not. Additionally this doesn't take into account any transactions that could be [minimally logged](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx) which will then need to have the entire extent touched backed up as part of the log (not saying this is happening, just another "not all transactions are the same" example).

### What's the bottom line?

There doesn't seem to be any issue here. The log backups are working properly, your VLFs are being re-used, life actually seems to be pretty good! The fact that the log backups might be increasing in size during a normal day is fine, in fact there are many places that generate TBs of log backups a day without issue.